# creating a universal window-based iphone app without generated xib file

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, universal

I am trying to create a Window-based Universal app for iPhone/iPad.  I used the Window-based template in XCode and it creates the necessary app delegate files for iPhone and iPad, but it also creates a xib file for each device, which I don't want to use -- I want to create my own views programmatically using my own view controllers, so I want to totally ignore the provided xib files.

I deleted the xib files from the project and updated the plist file accordingly to not reference them, thinking that now I can define my own views inside the app delegate, attach them to the window and display them.  Not so -- that doesn't work -- my created views are not displayed.  So I decided to just change the background color of the window to red and see if that shows -- it doesn't.  Tracing code execution does show that this code is executed.

So, what can and should I do?  Why is this happening?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change the

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

in main.m into

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"MyAppDelegate");
```

Then you have to initialize the window in the AppDelegate:

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: screenBounds] autorelease];
```

Then you can add views to the Window.